# Is there any Scala feature that allows you to call a method whose name is stored in a string?

Tags: scala, dynamic, language-features

Assuming you have a string containing the name of a method, an object that supports that method and some arguments, is there some language feature that allows you to call that dynamically?

Kind of like Ruby's `send` parameter.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this with reflection in Java:

```
class A {
  def cat(s1: String, s2: String) = s1 + " " + s2
}
val a = new A
val hi = "Hello"
val all = "World"
val method = a.getClass.getMethod("cat",hi.getClass,all.getClass)
method.invoke(a,hi,all)
```

And if you want it to be easy in Scala you can make a class that does this for you, plus an implicit for conversion:

```
case class Caller[T>:Null<:AnyRef](klass:T) {
  def call(methodName:String,args:AnyRef*):AnyRef = {
    def argtypes = args.map(_.getClass)
    def method = klass.getClass.getMethod(methodName, argtypes: _*)
    method.invoke(klass,args: _*)
  }
}
implicit def anyref2callable[T>:Null<:AnyRef](klass:T):Caller[T] = new Caller(klass)
a call ("cat","Hi","there")
```

Doing this sort of thing converts compile-time errors into runtime errors, however (i.e. it essentially circumvents the type system), so use with caution.

(Edit: and see the use of NameTransformer in the link above--adding that will help if you try to use operators.)

Comment: I am getting error on the following. `List(1, 2) call ("take", 1)`. The error is `type mismatch; found : Int(1) required: AnyRef Note: an implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous. This is to avoid a blanket implicit which 
 would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef. You may wish to use a type ascription: x: java.lang.Integer.`  Is there a way to handle primitive types? ( I want to dynamically generate the argument list...may be a list of `Any`)

Comment: @dips - You can `.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` on the way in (works with `Any` also), or `1: java.lang.Integer` as the error suggests.  Or you can match primitives and handle case-by-case if you really need to, though you ought not need to here.

Comment: Thanks! So my `call` function signature now takes `args: Any*` and I convert it to `AnyRef*` in the body of `call` as `args map {_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]}`. Hope this is fine. Don't know the subtleties, hence asking.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for lists. The list is passed as `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` to the method instead of `List[Type]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @ArthurC - You can encode the name the same way the compiler does, either by hand (see http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala for a translation table), or I think there's an externally-callable compiler method that does it whose name I forget.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the parameter type from `List[Ticket]` to `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Ticket]`. It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: I am getting a `NullPointerException` at `def argtypes = args.map(_.getClass)` when I pass an argument as null to this function. Any suggestions how to avoid that?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  It's called reflection.  [Here's a link to one way, using some experimental stuff](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)  However you should remember that Scala is not a dynamic language, and may not be able to easily do some things that scripting languages can do.  You're probably better doing a match on the string, and then calling the right method.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you can!**
You would need `.invoke()` method of the method object. Simple example below:

```
 import scala.util.Try

 case class MyCaseClass(i: String) {
 def sayHi = {
     println(i)
   }
 }
 val hiObj = MyCaseClass("hi")
 val mtdName = "sayHi"
 // Method itself as an object
 val mtd = hiObj.getClass.getMethod(mtdName)
 Try {mtd.invoke(hiObj)}.recover { case _ => ()}
```

see code here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vasily802/WRsRpgSoSayhHBeAvogieg/9

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val commandExecutor = Map("cleanup" -> {()=> println("cleanup successfully")} )
commandExecutor: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,() => Unit] = Map(cleanup -> <function0>)

scala> val command="cleanup"
command: String = cleanup

scala> commandExecutor(command).apply
cleanup successfully
```

Comment: very clean alternative to reflection