# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-reflect

I am trying to call a function using a variable as String type dynamically i.e. variable will contain a function name as String. So, I need to call a function using that variable.

So, I am using Scala Reflection. It is working if the function is accepting datatype as Sting, But it is throwing error List[Map[String, Double]]

I used below link to refer a code

[Is there any Scala feature that allows you to call a method whose name is stored in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060395/is-there-any-scala-feature-that-allows-you-to-call-a-method-whose-name-is-stored)

and below is a test program which I am trying to test

```
package test

import scala.collection.immutable.Map

class DynamicaVariable {
 def cat(s1: List[Map[String, Double]]) = {
  println(s1)
 }
}

object DynamicaVariable{
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 val obj = new DynamicaVariable
 val data = List(
  Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 40.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 4.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 90.0, "d" -> 17.0)
)
 val functionName = "cat"
 val method = obj.getClass.getMethod(functionName,data.getClass)
 method.invoke(obj,data)
}
}
```

My scala version is 2.11.6 and I am using IntelliJ. I have checked the SDK version also. And unchecked the "Run worksheet in the compile process" under scala

But still no luck! Any idea will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps but calling the *getMethod* this way `val method = obj.getClass.getMethod(functionName, classOf[List[Map[String, Double]]])` worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described here [Runtime Classes in Java vs. Runtime Types in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html#runtime-classes-in-java-vs-runtime-types-in-scala)

> using Java reflection on Scala classes might return surprising or incorrect results

It seems for your case, as *data* is of type *scala.collection.immutable.List*, you need to use Scala reflection to get the type of the *data* val at runtime. Here is an example

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.classTag

class DynamicaVariable {
    def cat(s1: List[Map[String, Double]]) = {
        println(s1)
    }
}

object DynamicaVariable{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val obj = new DynamicaVariable
        val data = List(Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0)
                        , Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 40.0, "d" -> 2.0)
                        , Map("a" -> 4.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0)
                        , Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 90.0, "d" -> 17.0))
        val functionName = "cat"
        val method = obj.getClass.getMethod(functionName, getClassOf(data).runtimeClass)

        method.invoke(obj,data)
    }

    def getClassOf[T: ClassTag](obj: T) = classTag[T]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I give a workable solution below that employs *scala reflection* vs the java/scala hybrid of @ValentinCarnu.

I am not a reflection guru, and so I do not know if the below is idiomatic.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

class DynamicaVariable {
  def cat(s1: List[Map[String, Double]]) = {
    println(s1)
  }
}

object DynamicaVariable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val obj = new DynamicaVariable
    val data = List(
      Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0),
      Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 40.0, "d" -> 2.0),
      Map("a" -> 4.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0),
      Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 90.0, "d" -> 17.0)
    )
    val functionName = "cat"
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val instanceMirror: ru.InstanceMirror = mirror.reflect(obj)
    val classSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(obj.getClass)
    val termName: ru.MethodSymbol = classSymbol.info.decl(ru.TermName(functionName)).asMethod


    val methodMirror: ru.MethodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(termName)
    methodMirror.apply(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed: https://medium.com/@giposse/scala-reflection-d835832ed13a and  https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html