# Error while Passing arguments to methods using scala reflection

Tags: scala

Error while passing arguments to methods. I have an object `builddeequ_rules` and calling methods using Scala reflection.

```
  def build(rules: List[Map[String, Any]]): Check = {
    for (constraint <- rules) {
     val name = constraint("name")
     val args = constraint("args")
     val hiObj = builddeequ_rules
     val mtd = hiObj.getClass.getMethod(name.toString,args.getClass)
     mtd.invoke(hiObj,args)
    }



import com.amazon.deequ.checks.{Check, CheckLevel}

object builddeequ_rules {
   var checks = Check(CheckLevel.Warning, "Data unit test")

def isComplete(args: Any)  {
   val arg = args.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
   val columnName = arg("column").toString
  checks = checks.isComplete(columnName)
 }

def isUnique(args: Any)  {
   val arg = args.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
   val columnName = arg("column").toString
  checks = checks.isUnique(columnName)
 }
def isPositive(args: Any)  {
   val arg = args.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
   val columnName = arg("column").toString
  checks = checks.isPositive(columnName)
 }
```

I am getting below error. Need help!

> Error: type mismatch;
> found   : Any
> required: Object
> mtd.invoke(hiObj,args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.Object` is more or less `scala.AnyRef`. `scala.Any` is (simplyfying) a superset of objects and primitives. So the compiler is warning you, that you are trying to pass something that could potentially be primitive (`Any`) as `java.lang.Object`.

On bytecode level `Any` will quite often be just `Object`, sure, but Scala's type system make the distinction between things that are "natively" `Object`s and things that could involve autoboxing to make them `Object`s, and that's the error you see.

So the solution here would be to have this object annotated as `AnyRef` or even better, as `java.lang.Object` to clearly show that you want to use it for something Java/JVM-specific.

Comment: I annotated `args ` as `java.land.Object`, But now i am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: builddeequ_rules$.isComplete(scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1)` error

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by referring this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044552/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-scala-collection-immutable-coloncolon. Used Scala reflection instead of Java reflection.